# How get the size of a Set object on a specific key value?

Tags: javascript, object, set

I need to know number of items which `item.status` is `true`. How can I get it?

```js
const set1 = new Set([
  {
    name: 'AA',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'BB',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'CC',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'DD',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'EE',
    status: false
  }
]);
```

In this example need to get `2`.
I want to do something like this:

```
set1.filter( item => item.status === true ).length
```

But don't know how filter in `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
const count = Array.from(set1).filter(val => val.status == true).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no shortcut, you have to count them (one way or another):

```
let count = 0;
for (const {status} of set1) {
    if (status) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

```js
const set1 = new Set([
  {
    name: 'AA',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'BB',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'CC',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'DD',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'EE',
    status: false
  }
]);

let count = 0;
for (const {status} of set1) {
    if (status) {
        ++count;
    }
}
console.log(`Count where status is true: ${count}`);
```

Or if you like `reduce` for things like this (I don't) you can spread the elements out into an array and the call `reduce` on it:

```
const count = [...set1].reduce((acc, {status}) => acc + (status ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

```js
const set1 = new Set([
  {
    name: 'AA',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'BB',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'CC',
    status: false
  },
  {
    name: 'DD',
    status: true
  },
  {
    name: 'EE',
    status: false
  }
]);

const count = [...set1].reduce((acc, {status}) => acc + (status ? 1 : 0), 0);
console.log(`Count where status is true: ${count}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.filter()` and then `Array.length` of the result to find the item count:

```js
const set1 = new Set([ { name: 'AA', status: false }, { name: 'BB', status: true }, { name: 'CC', status: false }, { name: 'DD', status: true }, { name: 'EE', status: false } ]);

const count = [...set1].filter(item => item.status).length;
console.log("Count:", count)
```